# Difference between last interaction and last non direct interaction for google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, attribution

Would someone be able to explain the difference between last interaction and last non direct interaction on google analytics model comparison tool for me please?

See below image:

Last interaction - my understanding is that on a last click basis, there were 40 conversions attributed to direct via this model

Last Google Ads click - via this attribution method, 28 conversions were attributed. Meaning according to google ads 28 of those conversions were from adwords, but on last click basis 40 of those conversions were last click direct.

Last non-direct click - this is where I am getting stuck. As last non-direct ignores direct, I would think last non direct interaction would 0 for channel= direct?

Any insights would be appreciated!

[Image of model comparison tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wjCO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user start a session from Organic and then makes another session as Direct, in the *last click non direct* model the conversion is attributed to the **Organic**, in the `last interaction` instead to the **Direct** one.

If there are only direct sessions (one or more), the conversion is attributed to the **Direct** (because it's like it's the last click non direct unless there is only direct).

Comment: Thank you Michele, that makes sense. However, I am still stuck on why (as per my screenshot in the link above) the Last Non-direct click for Direct traffic is reflecting 21 conversions. I would think it would reflect 0 conversions?

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if it is clear :)